# intellij, fix missing imports on all files?

Tags: intellij-idea, find-replace

After a find+replace on a large project, I realized I used a static class from the project not already imported in all files.

Is there any functionality in Intellij that is equivalent to opening all files and fixing the missing import? I don't think I have to worry about classname edge cases, it should be the first option on all cases.

Comment: Please try to set "Add unambiguous imports on the fly" (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html#automatically-add-import-statements), then right click on project root and select "Optimize imports"